# Set of all possible matches in SymPy

Tags: pattern-matching, sympy

I would like to match a pattern to an expression in such a way that returns all possible matchings. Using SymPy I can match my pattern to my expression in a single arbitrarily selected way. How can I use pattern matching to obtain the entire set (up to arbitrary renamings)

Currently I can do this

```
>>> p, q = Wild('p'), Wild('q')
>>> x, y, z = symbols('x,y,z')

>>> (p+q).matches(x+y+z)
{p: y + z, q: x}
```

I want to do this

```
>>> (p+q).allmatches(x+y+z)
{{p: x, q: y + z}, {p: y, q: x + z}, {p: z, q: x + y}}
```

Note that each possible partitioning is represented.
I would be willing to implement this myself. What are standard algorithms for pattern matching that produce all possible matches?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd have to target the matches with all possible sets of excludes, like

```
In [16]: [(x + y + z).match(Wild('p', exclude=i) + Wild('q', exclude=set([x, y, z]) - set(i))) for i in subsets([x, y, z])]
Out[16]: [{p: x + y + z, q: 0}, {p: y + z, q: x}, {p: x + z, q: y}, {p: x + y, q: z}, {p: z, q: x + y}, {p: y, q: x + z}, {p: x, q: y + z}, {p: 0, q: x + y + z}]
```

(`subsets` is the SymPy function from `sympy.utilities.iterables`).

Comment: Note that each `p` and `q` in those dictionaries will compare differently because they have different `exclude`s on them.  So you'll need to keep track of the `p`s and `q`s to access them later.

Comment: How would this solution generalize to more complex expressions and patterns with more wilds?

Comment: I'm not clear what a more general expression would look like to you. Obviously, you could get the above by just using subsets directly.